# The probability of an ant rarely visiting the points with both coordinates even

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

A point of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is painted white if at least one of its coordinates is odd. An ant is moving in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

At each integer time $t$ the ant is
at a point in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and it chooses one of points in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ at distance $1$ with uniform
probability, and it moves there before time $t + 1$.

For an integer $n$, denote by $P_n$
the probability that among the previous $n$ integer times the ant was at least $90\%$
of the time at a white point.

Prove that $P_n$ decreases exponentially with $n$. Can
you compute the rate?

Comment: Hi Ryan! Please, alongside the question, can you add details on what do you have already tried? This will facilitate our task on aswerers. Just edit your question and add your efforts! It is easy!

Comment: Hi candyman, i really dont have any clue about how to do this problem

Comment: Have you tried to rephrase the problem? You can see the problem as a random walk problem on a graph $G=(V,E)$ with 4 vertices ($V=\{0,1,2,3\}$) where vertex $i$ would represent the set of points with $i$ coordinates odd. Then you can explicit the transition matrix and work from there.

Answer (score 2):

As the coordinates of points in this question can only be distinguished modulo $2$, your question is equivalent to the following one:

> Suppose our ant starts in a vertex $v(0)$ of the $H(3, 2)$ Hamming graph (or, equivalently, the edge graph of a cube). At each integer time the ant moves from his current vertex to one of the adjacent ones with uniform probability. Suppose $v(t)$ is the position of ant in the time $t$, $w$ - some fixed vertex. Let's denote $P(t, w, v(0))$ as the probability, that $\frac{|\{0 \leq \tau \leq t|v(\tau) = w\}|}{t} \leq \frac{1}{10}$. Prove, that $\exists \lim_{t \to \infty} (P(t, w, v(0)))^{\frac{1}{t}} = p(w, v(0))$ and find that $p(v, w(0)$.

As $H(3, 2)$ is highly symmetric, the only difference between the ant's position is the ants current distant from $w$, which can be $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$. Those distances are states of a finite Markov chain with transition matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 \\
  0  & \frac{2}{3}  & 0 & 1  \\
  0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

The stationary distribution of this Markov chain is $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{10} \\
\frac{3}{10}\\
 \frac{3}{10}\\
  \frac{1}{10} 
 \end{pmatrix}$

From that we can conclude, that $\frac{|\{0 \leq \tau \leq t|v(\tau) = w\}|}{t}$ converges almost surely to $\frac{1}{10}$, because of the Theorem C.1 from ["Markov Chains and Mixing Times" by David A. Levin](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/mcmt2e.pdf), which states:

> Suppose $X$ is the set of all states of an irreducible aperiodic finite-state Markov chain $a(t)$, $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of $a(t)$ and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is some arbitrary function. Then $\frac{\sum_{s=0}^t f(a(t))}{t}$ converges almost surely to $\sum{x \in X}f(x)\pi(x)$.

And from that we can conclude that the probability that $\frac{|\{0 \leq \tau \leq t|v(\tau) = w\}|}{t} \leq \frac{1}{10}$ tends to $1$ and as $t \to \infty$. Thus such $p(w, v(0))$ does indeed exist and equals $1$.